# MySQL 5.1 Logging Slow Queries - Right Syntax?

Tags: mysql

I'm having some issues logging the slow queries in my MySQL 5.1 instance.  It seems to be logging every query, not just the slow ones.

Here's a sample of the logging...

```
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 0.000000  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 11
SET timestamp=1398191470;
SELECT count(distinct(user_id)) as user_id from user_sessions where role='bidder';
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Query_time: 0.000000  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 9  Rows_examined: 11
SET timestamp=1398191470;
SELECT user_name FROM user_sessions WHERE last_access_ts > '2014-04-22 14:30:59';
```

Here's the entries in my mysql.ini file....

```
long_query_time = 3
slow_query_log
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have "log-queries-not-using-indexes" turned on. That causes the server to consider all queries that are not using indexes to be "slow".

To resolve your issue, either remove "log-queries-not-using-indexes" or add indexes on "role" and "last_access_ts" fields to user_sessions table.